# Rectangle tiling

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The diagonal of a rectangular tile with integer sides is one-third of the length of the diagonal of a row of tiles identical to the original one. If the perimeter of the single tile is 24 cm, how many tiles are in the row?

This question is from an math competition where no calculators are allowed. Is there an efficient method to do this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could say the sides of the tile are $x$ and $12-x$.

Then if one diagonal is three times another diagonal, that's the same as saying that the square of the diagonals are in a ratio of $9:1$

$$9*d_1^2=d_2^2$$
So you can set up this equation using the Pythagorean Theorem (repeating the tiles down the side of length $x$ and find an integer value of $k$. 
$$9*(x^2 + (12-x)^2) = (k * x)^2 + (12-x)^2$$
I don't know how easy it is to solve but Wolfram lists an integer solution of $k=9$

Comment: Is it reasonable to just solve that last equation wrt $x$ (via the usual trick for quadratics) and read off what $k$ must be to get an integer?

Comment: @turkeyhundt Yeah I used the method above, but solving it was tricky and there was a lot of number calculations along the way.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl That might be the way to go actually, I'll give that a go. Thanks for all the help btw.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b$ be the horizontal and vertical dimensions, respectively, of a single tile, and let $n$ be the number of tiles.

Since the perimeter of a single tile is $24$, we have $a+b = 12$, hence $1 \le a \le 11$.

From the specified conditions,
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(na)^2 + b^2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2+b^2=\frac{1}{9}((na)^2 + b^2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&9a^2+9b^2=n^2a^2 + b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(n^2-9)a^2=8b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(n^2-9)a^2=8(12-a)^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&n^2=\frac{17a^2-192a+1152}{a^2}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&17a^2-192a+1152\;\text{is a perfect square}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&17a^2-192a+1152\equiv 0\;\text{or}\;1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2a^2 \equiv 0\;\text{or}\;1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a \in \{3,6,9\}\qquad\text{[since $1 \le a \le 11$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Three cases is a lot better than $11$ . . .

If $a = 9$, then $b = 12 - a = 12 - 9 = 3$, but then
$$(n^2-9)a^2=8b^2\implies n^2 - 9 = \frac{8}{9}$$
which is not an  integer, contradiction.

If $a = 6$, then $b = 12 - a = 12 - 6 = 6$, but then
$$(n^2-9)a^2=8b^2\implies n^2 - 9 = 8 \implies n^2 = 17$$
which is not an perfect square, contradiction.

If $a = 3$, then $b=12-a = 12-3 = 9$, and then
$$(n^2-9)a^2=8b^2\implies n^2 - 9 = 72 \implies n^2 = 81\implies n = 9$$
which yields the solution triple $(a,b,n) = (3,9,9)$.

Comment: Wow thanks for the response. Solution is great but could you explain why a perfect square $k^2\equiv 0$ or  $1\pmod 3$?

Comment: There are only $3$ possible values of $k$, mod $3$. If $k\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then $k^2\equiv 0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. If $k\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $k^2\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Finally, if $k\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $k^2\equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Thus, the only possible values for $k^2$, mod $3$, are $0$ or $1$.